# EWS exception : "Connection failed. Try later."

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, exchangewebservices

Every time I try to call the server, I get an error code : `ErrorConnectionFailed` with `Connection failed. Try later.` message.

I suspect that it comes from the fact that the credentials of `service` are empty. Although I have no idea why. If I create the credentials manually using my windows account login and password, it works fine : `new WebCredentials(login, password, domain);`

I have a console program that works fine (see below), **but it does not on a web site.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var service = GetContextualService(email);
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(validEmailId));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static ExchangeService GetContextualService(string email)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

    // I don't even need credentials on a Console program to make it work
    //service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
    //service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(email, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

    return service;
}

private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = false;

    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

    // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
    // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
    // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

While using on a website even with `new WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);`, it returns an exception. (see below)

```
private ExchangeService GetContextualService(string email)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
    //service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    service.AutodiscoverUrl(email, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

    return service;
}

[HttpPost]
public List<InternetMessageHeader> GetMailHeader(JObject data)
{
    ExchangeService service = GetContextualService(data.GetValue("email").Value<string>());
    ItemId id = new ItemId(data.GetValue("mailId").Value<string>());
    // EXCEPTION BELOW
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, id);

    return email.InternetMessageHeaders.ToList();
}
```

Why does any call to EWS returns me an exception ?

Why is it working fine on a console program and not on a web server ?

Any thought is welcome !

Comment: If it works using EWSEditor, I guess it means it works using the EWS XML. Then what could make it not work using Managed API ?

Comment: Actually the EWSEditor uses the EWS Managed API, that error is generally a throttling response how many items are you trying to open at once ?

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Most likely this is a kerberos Delegation issue see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2012/07/26/exchange-web-services-and-sharepoint-without-applicationimpersonation.aspx

Comment: By default, a console program runs with the same permissions as that of the current logged in user, whereas a WebSite (I am assuming IIS here) runs with different permissions probably IUSER. 

This means that the default credentials will not generally authenticate for external services.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly based on the code you posted, all I can say is that when you call AutoDiscoverUrl() it may not be talking to the same server that you need to talk to with EWS.  Altho typically AD and EWS are on the CAS, it's possible (I think) to get an EWS URL that points to some other server.  I've not been in the code in the EWS Editor in some time, but if it does not call the Managed API, it might do AD slightly differently.  I'd suggest calling out the EWS URL before you try the Bind() and seeing if you can paste it into a browser.  (It'll redirect you OWA, but the connection will be proven.)  I'd also call out the AD URL in the redirection callback so you know who you're talking to.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Looks like the issue comes from the fact that the **credentials are empty**. And the thought about this is that it could be caused by Visual Studio when it is launched as Administrator. The thing is I don't know how to fix this when Visual Studio is started as Administrator.